# JDBC driver problem in OSGI

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, osgi

I am trying to have an OSGI bundle access a MYSQL DB, using Eclipse as my IDE (Windows 7 x64). I am able to load the jdbc connector. The actual .jar is placed in all \bin folders in the java install directories, along with the \bin folder of the bundle. I have set the environment classpath variable to this folder also. I have an error stating that the driver is not suitable. I know OSGI has some issues with drivers etc. Can someone recommend a way to circumvent this?

```
ClassLoader DBHCL = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
DBHCL.loadClass("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver", true, DBHCL).newInstance();
System.out.println("Class Loaded");
//DriverManager.getDriver("jdbc:mysql://localhost/timedb");
//System.out.println("Driver Gotten");
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL + DBName,username,password);
System.out.println("Connection Created");
stmt = conn.createStatement();
System.out.println("Statement Created");
connFlag = true;
```

Console Output, Error: osgi> start 7 Data Base Service (MYSQL) Starting Class Loaded No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost/timedb Exception in thread "Thread-1" INSERT INTO appliance1...

Does anybody have any insight into this problem?

I have tried making a separate bundle solely for the jdbc driver and exporting/importing this to the appropriate bundle, but no luck.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In your code snippet, you get the `SystemClassLoader`, and you ask it for the `"com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"`. Given that that call doesn't give you a `ClassNotFoundException`, we can conclude the system classloader can find the class for you; the driver will then register itself to the `DriverManager`.

However, you don't see the same `DriverManager` that the MySQL driver does! The MySQL driver sees the one from the system classloader, but your code (`conn = DriverManager. ...`) uses the one from the bundle's own classloader. These are two different classes, hence, no suitable driver is found.

My solution would be to *not* use the `SystemClassLoader` (which you shouldn't do in OSGi anyway, unless you know exactly what you're doing), but use the bundle's classloader. So, I would

- not put the MySQL jar on the system classpath, but let OSGi do the hard work. You can put the jar in a bundle, and put the jar on the `Bundle-ClassPath`. You can then choose either to keep it private to your bundle (if you're the only one using it), or export the packages.
- In stead of using the system classloader, use the bundle's classloader. This can be as simple as using `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")`; this will do the right thing.